# Eclipse link to external classes

Tags: eclipse

I'm working with Eclipse and am able to create projects, but I want to start building my own libraries.

How can I link to class/library files from outside the Eclipse environment?

lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you are developing Java projects with Eclipse).

1. Right click on your project name to display bring up context menu
2. Select **Project properties...** to display properties panel
3. Select **Java Build Path**
4. Select the **Libraries** tab

You can now add a external library in a variety of ways: A JAR that belongs to another Eclipse project, an external JAR, a directory, etc.

Comment: Hello,  I've seen these instructions. However, I don't have a project yet. I want to create some libraries I can use in multiple projects. How do I create one of these libraries?

Comment: A library in Java is just a JAR file.  You don't need Eclipse for that.  Simply compile and create a JAR (both using tools that come with the Java SDK).  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Hello,  I guess I am thinking something along the lines of how AS3 works. For AS3 projects, you just set a path to the source code, and it compiles it into your code. I'm familiar with JAR files. Are you saying I have to compile my library into a JAR then import that into my project? So I would have to compile twice each time I update my library files?

Comment: AS3 as in ActionScript?  Those generate SWC & SWF files.  You then use (link) the SWC that you generated (or somebody _else_ generated) in _your_ code.  Similarly in Java you bundle your library logic a JAR (just a zip with other metadata).  Then you can link the project that **needs** this logic to the JAR.  The JAR needs to only include bytecode.  Therefore it isn't compiled per se when you build your project.  However if you make changes to your library you definitely have to rebuild the library JAR (just as you would with your SWC in the AS3 case).